# Product of operators, eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

If I've two hermitian operators let's say A and B,then their eigenfunctions(vectors) form a basis... If I now take a product of both of them and create a new operator AB (composition of both), that operator will be hermitian as well(if A and b commute), but what about its basis ?

**Question:** Is it simply all possible combinations of $|A\rangle$$|B\rangle$, thats the product of eigenfunctions of the A and B operator?

**Question:** Can all functions be written in the A or B basis?

Example: I have two particles 1 and 2, their angular momentum operators for the "z direction" are $ L_{z1}$ and $L_{z2}$ , they are both hermitian, so I can calculate their eigenfunctions, that form a basis(this are the spherical harmonics$ |l_1,m_1\rangle $ and $|l_2 ,m_2\rangle$ ), I now create the $ L_{z1}$$L_{z2}$  operator. If I now calculate the eigenfunctions of this new operator, they will form a basis, is this basis composed of function in the form of $|l_1,m_1\rangle |l_2,m_2\rangle$, so just a product of the eigenfunctions of both operators?

Comment: Since $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger = BA \neq AB$, the operator is Hermitian if and only if $A$ and $B$  commute. I'm not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is probably tensor product, not composition.

Comment: I read the question to ask for the properties of eigenvalues of the product of Hermitian matrices. Is the product of Hermitian matrices Hermitian, and are the eigenvectors of A and B still eigenvectors of the product. I don't like to edit but I think it's a salvageable question...

Comment: Sorry guys, I've added an example, hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As " ACuriousMind " said the product of AB is Hermitian iff A and B commutes .

Considering they commute, then one can obtain a common eigen-basis for both A and B. Also Eigen-basis of either A or B can be used to diagonalize the AB operator.

Here goes the proof(i'll be taking only non-degenerate case, as degenerate one will require more detailed proof).

Consider $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ be the eigen-vectors of A and B with eigen-values $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$ respectively.

so we have the following,

$[A,B] = AB-BA = 0$ and,

$A|a\rangle = \lambda_a|a\rangle$ , $B|b\rangle = \lambda_b|b\rangle$.

as the operators are hermitian, they have real eigen-values.

Part 1 : 
If  set G1 and G2 are the eigen-basis of linear operator  A , then any vector from G2 can be written as a linear combination of vectors of G1. Which in turn will lead to the conclusion that G1 and G2 are essentially the same except for a constant multiplication of a complex constant, i.e

$A|a_{G2}\rangle = \lambda_a^{G2}|a_{G2}\rangle = \lambda_a^{G2}c_a^{G1,G2}|a_{G1}\rangle$, where $|a_{G2}\rangle$ and $|a_{G1}\rangle$ are from set G1 and G2 and $c_a^{G1,G2}$ is a constant

Part 2:

$AB|b\rangle = \lambda_bA|b\rangle  = BA|b\rangle$

Which says, $A|b\rangle$ is also an eigen vector of operator B with $\lambda_b$ as an eigen-value.

Using the result from part 1, we can say that vector $A|b\rangle = c_a|b\rangle$.

Hence set of vectors $|b\rangle$ can be taken as a common eigen-vector set of both operators A and B.

Also as for your question, eigen-vectors of the operator AB,

$AB|b\rangle = \lambda_bc_a|b\rangle$.

Hope this answers your query( though it was not clear in your question).

Comment: I would also suggest you to read " Eugen Merzbacher quantum mechanics"

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! This is what I was looking for.